# Process big pipe seperated file with and without multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a big file (more than 10G and 40m rows). Each line has pipe seperated fields and one of the fields includes JSON.

Example of Input line:

```
1|10|{"DelTime":1572299058000,"ValidFrom":1547506800474,"ValidTo":1572217199000,"Units":1,"ID1":1,"ID2":"1","ID3":"1","ID4":"1"}|10000000|
```

Example of Output line:

```
10|(1|1|10000000|1|1|20190114180000|20191027185959)
```

I need to extract some specific fields and change epoch time to specific date format. My code is the following (After including  RomanPerekhrest suggestion):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys,json,time

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
                fields = line.split('|')
                json_attributes = json.loads(fields[2])
                print (fields[1], "(" + json_attributes['ID1'], json_attributes['ID2'], fields[3], json_attributes['ID3'], fields[0], time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.localtime(json_attributes['ValidFrom']/1000)), time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.localtime(json_attributes['ValidTo']/1000)) + ")", sep='|')
```

This in my PC (is going to run in a multiprocessor server) is doing around 100 seconds for 1000000 lines. Find bellow the cProfile:

```
         14001936 function calls (14001865 primitive calls) in 100.021 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   20.052   20.052  100.021  100.021 FUC3.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:48(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:74(_Feature)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:75(__init__)
  1000000    3.073    0.000   40.194    0.000 __init__.py:293(loads)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:49(normalize_encoding)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 __init__.py:71(search_function)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.008    0.008 __init__.py:99(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:77(__new__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 decoder.py:17(_floatconstants)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.005 decoder.py:2(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decoder.py:274(JSONDecoder)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decoder.py:304(__init__)
  1000000    5.564    0.000   37.121    0.000 decoder.py:361(decode)
  1000000   26.296    0.000   26.296    0.000 decoder.py:372(raw_decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:101(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 encoder.py:2(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:70(JSONEncoder)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:27(hex_decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:45(Codec)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:52(IncrementalEncoder)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:57(IncrementalDecoder)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:62(StreamWriter)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:65(StreamReader)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:70(getregentry)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hex_codec.py:8(<module>)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.001 re.py:188(compile)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.001 re.py:226(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 scanner.py:2(<module>)
       14    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.000 sre_compile.py:179(_compile_charset)
       14    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 sre_compile.py:208(_optimize_charset)
       54    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:25(_identityfunction)
        4    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_compile.py:259(_mk_bitmap)
     26/6    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.000 sre_compile.py:33(_compile)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:355(_simple)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_compile.py:360(_compile_info)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:473(isstring)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.001 sre_compile.py:479(_code)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.001 sre_compile.py:494(compile)
       50    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:127(__len__)
       91    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:131(__getitem__)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:135(__setitem__)
       25    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:139(append)
    35/15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:141(getwidth)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:179(__init__)
      118    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:183(__next)
       80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:196(match)
       94    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:202(get)
       18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:226(_class_escape)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:258(_escape)
     13/6    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 sre_parse.py:302(_parse_sub)
     15/6    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 sre_parse.py:380(_parse)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 sre_parse.py:676(parse)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:68(__init__)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:73(opengroup)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:84(closegroup)
       26    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:91(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 {__import__}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_sre.compile}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_struct.unpack}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {binascii.a2b_hex}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x7f2575fe0e00}
       32    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {chr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {hasattr}
      111    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
1000434/1000419    0.353    0.000    0.353    0.000 {len}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {max}
      340    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  2000000    0.881    0.000    0.881    0.000 {method 'end' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
       32    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
       38    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  2000000    4.028    0.000    4.028    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
       32    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects}
  1000001    1.997    0.000    1.997    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'translate' of 'str' objects}
       56    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {min}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {ord}
  1000000   11.911    0.000   11.911    0.000 {print}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
  2000000   17.697    0.000   17.697    0.000 {time.localtime}
  2000000    8.162    0.000    8.162    0.000 {time.strftime}
```

I also tried instead of reading line by line, to read a lot of lines together but it's almost the same execution time:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys,json,time

inputfile = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
tmp_lines = inputfile.readlines(1000000)
while tmp_lines:
    for line in tmp_lines:
        fields = line.split('|')
        json_attributes = json.loads(fields[2])
        print (fields[1], "(" + json_attributes['ID1'], json_attributes['ID2'], fields[3], json_attributes['ID3'], fields[0], time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.localtime(json_attributes['ValidFrom']/1000)), time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.localtime(json_attributes['ValidTo']/1000)) + ")", sep='|')
```

I have the following questions:

- Is there any way to make this faster without using multiprocessing or multithreading?
- I guess since I do not see difference when I read line by line or when I read many lines together, does that means that I am cpu-bound?
- I suppose it makes sense to use multiprocessing or multithreading, since there are enough resources on the server that the script will run but I really don't have any experience with this. I cannot read the whole file in the memory, since the server won't have this amount of memory (10GB) free just for my python script.

The solution should be able to run on Python 2.7.5

Comment: move `json.loads(fields[2])` into a separate statement to avoid duplicate parsing ... and try again

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest. This was a great feedback. Currently it takes 100 secs in order to process 1000000 lines! great improvment!